# Taking SUM of values that are obtained from SUM of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a MSSQL  query in which I am taking grandtotal, which is a SUM of values that are obtained by taking SUM.

```
   select
      s.name
     ,SUM(b.dAmount) as total
     ,SUM(SUM(b.dAmount)) as grandtotal
   from t_sales a
        left outer join t_cust b on (b.dId=a.id)
   where a.custId=@customerId
   GROUP BY b.name;
```

I can get the name and total but grandtotal doesn't return any value. Please let me know what is the correct way to take SUM of values that are SUM of another values.Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with `sub-queries`?

Comment: In SQL Server, I think you're thinking of the window function `SUM() OVER ()`.  In this case it would be `SUM(SUM(b.dAmount)) OVER () as grandtotal`. In MySQL you would need to use a subquery.

Comment: What is your platform: MySQL or MS SQL Server?  Please adjust your tags accordingly.

Comment: Adjusted tags for OP.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 select
      b.name
     ,SUM(b.dAmount) as total
     , SUM(SUM(b.dAmount)) OVER () as grandtotal

   from t_sales a
        left outer join t_cust b on (b.dId=a.id)
   where a.custId=@customerId
   GROUP BY b.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can't do this without either using a nested subquery or by using the `GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP`

For your case, I'd recommend just using the `WITH ROLLUP` keyword, this will add another row to the result set with the grand total.  It will also avoid returning the same total on every row of the set.

```
  SELECT IFNULL(s.name, 'Total'), SUM(b.dAmount) as total
   FROM t_sales a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN t_cust b ON (b.dId = a.id)
   WHERE a.custId = @customerId
   GROUP BY b.name WITH ROLLUP;
```

If you're not directly displaying the results you can remove the `IFNULL(s.name, 'Total')` bit - the super-aggregate will have nulls on all columns not in the `SUM()`

Comment: I am using MSSQL is this for MySQL?

Comment: You had tagged your question with MySQL, and that's what I have experience with.  I believe this will still work in MSSQL, although behaviour might be slightly different - give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
create table #t_sales (name varchar(100),amount numeric(18,2))  

INSERT INTO #t_sales (name,amount)
values  ('A',100.00)
    ,('B',200.00)
    ,('C',300.00)
    ,('C',400.00)

INSERT INTO #t_sales (name,amount)
values  ('A',100.00)
    ,('B',200.00)
    ,('C',300.00)
    ,('C',400.00)

SELECT CASE WHEN (GROUPING(name) = 1) THEN 'GRAND TOTAL'
        ELSE ISNULL(name, ' ')
   END AS [type]
   ,SUM(amount) AS TOTAL
FROM #t_sales
GROUP BY name WITH ROLLUP
```